# Creating a "note" in HelpScout with Python using their API

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to automate some stuff in HelpScout, but have some trouble to find (and understand) the correct parameters to use their API to add a simple "note" to a conversation. I already read [the documentation](https://developer.helpscout.com/help-desk-api/conversations/create-thread/), but as I am quite new to this stuff and couldn't find the solution on my own.

Let's say I want to add a simple note like "Customer ID: 1234" to a conversation. As far as I understand I need to provide the API key, the type of the request (note) and the body with my text?

requests.post("https://api.helpscout.net/v1/conversations/xxxxxxx.json", auth=
   (TOKEN,'X')).

Added authentication already, but have no clue how to add the rest. Any hint would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by opening a thread inside a conversation:

```
import requests

TOKEN = "123abc..." # your helpscout Token

new_note = {"createdBy": {"id": 123456, "type": "user"}, "type": "note", "body": "test_note", "status": "active"}
r = requests.post("https://api.helpscout.net/v1/conversations/123456789.json", auth=(TOKEN,'X'), headers=headers, data=json.dumps(new_note))
print(r.status_code) # Should be 201 if correct
```

Replace the ID inside `createdBy` with the user which is creating the note and add the correct converstation id after `.../conversations/<id>.json`.